# Were mushrooms vegetables to Romans?

Tags: classical-latin, passage-request, cibus, biology

Mushrooms are taxonomically clearly distinct from plants and animals (and other kingdoms), but in "cuisine taxonomy" they are typically included in plants.
The word "vegetables" in a restaurant's menu can well include mushrooms — no matter how much I personally dislike this inclusion.

I would like to know whether the Romans saw mushrooms as plants or vegetables.
Are there passages in Roman literature that discuss or hint at the inclusion or exclusion of mushrooms within plants?
Any mention like "mushrooms and plants", "mushrooms and other plants", or "mushrooms are plants" would be interesting.
Any word for "mushroom" or "plant" is possible, for example *boletus* and *holus*.
The context can be food or taxonomy.
I did not manage to find anything.
(I purposely decided to leave the question broad, since I fear there is not much relevant extant material.)

Comment: It might be worthwhile looking at Aristotle or other Greek writers on botany -- though this wouldn't directly tell you what the Romans thought, it could be relevant as much or most Roman science was taken from the Greeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Apparently yes**.

Although I haven't found any explicitly *Roman* source, all evidence point to fungi being considered plants at their time, and into the XX century. This is what I have found so far:

- The author of [*De Plantis* I. 4. 30](https://books.google.cl/books?id=knBoAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA397&ots=K6JhNnTreO&dq=plantae%20sunt%20non%20habentes%20ramos%20nec%20folia%2C%20ut%20fungi&pg=PA397#v=onepage&q=plantae%20sunt%20non%20habentes%20ramos%20nec%20folia,%20ut%20fungi&f=false) considered them plants. The book is attributed to Aristotle (in which case the original is Greek, and the translator unknown, but also to [Nicolaus of Damascus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaus_of_Damascus) who would have written it in the I century BC (thanks brianpck:)

  > *Item plantae sunt nec ramos habentes nec folia, ut fungi et tuberes*
- According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungus#History) *"the seminal work in the development of mycology is considered to be the publication of Pier Antonio Micheli's 1729 work Nova plantarum genera"*. The title itself is eloquent in telling that they were considered plants at the time.
- Linnaeus in his [Sistema Naturae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systema_Naturae) (XVIII century) classified everything in nature into three *Kingdoms*, namely animals, plants and minerals. (*Regum animale, vegetabile*, and *lapideum*.) Modern taxonomical kingdoms started from these.) Apparently this was still taught on schools in the mid-XX century.
- The distinction of fungi from plants seems to be [XX century science](http://www.botany.hawaii.edu/faculty/wong/Bot201/Myxomycota/Introduction.htm) (possibly requiring modern genetics to tell them appart.)

  - There are examples of good scientific literature classing them together as late as the sixties [(Alexopoulos 1962)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3758063?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).
  - An early example of telling kingdoms appart is [Ainsworth and Bisby (1971)](https://books.google.cl/books?hl=en&lr=&id=IFD4_VFRDdUC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=Ainsworth%20and%20Bisby%20(1971)&ots=sZrTmgqkmd&sig=G8Ew75krDgw2Mmyy8GvTb_HZjHQ#v=onepage&q=Ainsworth%20and%20Bisby%20(1971)&f=false).

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Plants), *De Plantis* was probably written in the 1st c. BC by [Nicolaus of Damascus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaus_of_Damascus), which supports your conclusion.